# Adding custom Permanent/Temporary behaviours to a basic type

Tags: c#, design-patterns, architecture, xna

I have a basic core interface called IComponent.

```
public interface IComponent
{
    void Initialize();

    void Update();

    void Draw(Color tint);

    BoundingBox BoundingBox { get; }

    bool Initialized { get; }
}
```

It is used by any class that will drawable (button, text, texture, ...)

I want to develop a set of effects that can be applied to any IComponent, such as:

```
Shake(IComponent component, TimeSpan duration)
```

-> Causes the Component to vibrate for a given duration. It works by initially storing the center position of the passed component and offsetting it at each Update till duration ends.

```
Translate(IComponent component, Vector2 destination, TimeSpan timeToReach)
```

-> Causes the Component to move to the given destination after a certain time. It works by incrementally offsetting the component at each Update.

You can imagine more...

So assume I want a certain class (Texture : IComponent) to shake while also moving to a certain point. I thought of possibly using the decorator pattern like so:

Create a Texture => Wrap it in a Shake (5 sec duration) => Wrap it in a Translate (10 sec duration)

but there are some problems with that.

Primarily, The Shake wrapper would work fine alone with a static stationary texture, but combined with a Translate it would fail since it would keep returning the texture to its original position and it wont translate properly.

Secondly, while the translation will take 10 seconds to finish, the vibrating will take only 5 seconds, so afterwards I don't know how to automatically remove the Shake wrapper from within the chain, and also finally remove the Translate when its done, leaving behind the original texture.

Thirdly, the decorator pattern hides any specific functions of the wrapped object, so after wrapping a Texture with a Shake, I wont be able to invoke the setPixelColor() of Texture, unless I also create a second direct reference to Texture before wrapping it.

Any suggestions of how to tackle such a challenge elegantly are welcome. Thanks.

**Note**: In practice I am likely to apply those effects to probably 2% of all created objects that are IComponent.

Comment: Take a look at the builder patter with a method group syntax like `new Component().Vibrate().Shake().Translate();`

Comment: @sll I did refresh on the builder pattern, but am not sure I understand you. So it seems that you want to expand the IComponent interface with Shake(), Translate() and so on, and use the builder pattern to supply the component with the builders that will carry out those functions. But this means I have to go back and re-modify the IComponent interface each time I want to add/remove a new effect. And effects are really only applied to a very small subset of all the components I create. Also I dont see how this will solve my primary issue described in the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe another approach along the following lines.

In your example both shake and translate are Animation effects. All animations need some form of duration and are applied to a component. Which could lead to the following first take:

```
public interface IAnimationEffect
{
    IComponent targetComponent;
    int Duration { get; set; }
}
```

Duration of an animation may seem like a good initial approach, however, when you need to combine animations, each animation needs to manipulate the BoundingRect of its encapsulated IComponent over the same period of time as other animations. In order to be able to stack animations like this, the draw methods for the animation effects need to be instructed to draw a specific frame of the animation.

An improved version of the IAnimationEffect interface would be:

```
public interface IAnimationEffect
{
    IComponent targetComponent;
    int StartFrame { get; set; }
    int EndFrame { get; set; }
    void CalculateFrame(int frame);
}
```

Whichever class is responsible for drawing your IComponents (Lets call it `DrawingEngine` for now), is now also responsible for holding an internal List of all applicable animation effects. It also needs to have some sort of timeline and rendering logic in frames per second, so that calculations for a specific animation frame can be performed.

```
public class ShakeAnimationEffect : IAnimationEffect
{
    public IComponent TargetComponent { get; set; }
    public int StartFrame { get; set; }
    public int EndFrame { get; set; }
    // Some shake specific properties can be added, to control the type of vibration etc 
    // (could be a rotating vibration an updown shake), but these really should have dedicated classes of their own.

    public void CalculateFrame(int frame)
    {
        // your maths manipulations for calculating the bounds of the IComponent go here
    }
}

public class TranslateAnimation : IAnimationEffect
{
    public IComponent targetComponent { get; set; }
    public int StartFrame { get; set; }
    public int EndFrame { get; set; }
    public int TranslateX { get; set; } 
    public int TranslateY { get; set; }

    public void CalculateFrame(int frame)
    {
        // your maths manipulations for calculating the bounds of the IComponent go here
    }
}
```

As proposed above then your AnimationEffects classes do not have any responsibility for drawing IComponents, that remains the responsibility of the DrawingEngine.

What you would need to introduce directly before your DrawingLoop, is a loop for running all animation effects, all this would do is update the bounds of the objects that happen to have an animation effect associated with them. Then you carry on drawing the object as usual.

Suppose that you have something like this:

```
        // suppose your drawing engine has the following:
       List<IComponent> components = new List<IComponent>();

        //now just add the following 
       List<IAnimationEffect> animationEffects = new List<IAnimationEffect>(); 

        // create some animation effects and register them to your list
        animationEffects.Add(new ShakeAnimationEffect
          {
              TargetComponent = Lorry,
              StartFrame = 0,
              EndFrame = 150, //At 30 frames per second, this would be a 5sec animation
          }
        );

        //sample pseudecode
        RunAnimationCalculations();
        RunDrawingLoop();
```

All that RunAnimationCalculations would do is loop through through your animationEffects collection and run Calculate passing in the current frame so that the bounds of the IComponent are updated, before the frame is subsequently drawn.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks. This is what I eventually went with. I made a base class called IComEffect which is generic to enable work on various types. All these IComEffects will be hosted in a ComEffectManager class. Its all very similar to what you wrote, with the addition of a 'Finished' event for each IComEffect which the ComEffectManager subscribes to when an effect is added to it, and when the Finished event is triggered, the ComEffectManager would dispose of the IComEffect. I also added a TimeSpan StartDelay parameter to IComEffect so I can queue them up to start taking effect after each other.

Answer (score 0):

You can about something like this:

```
public Shake : ITransformation 
{
}

public Translate : ITransformation
{
}
```

`IComponent` interface defines also a collection of transformations applied to it:

```
public interface IComponent
{
    public IEnumerable<ITransformation> GetTransformation();
}
```

in some concrete implementation of the `Component`

```
public MyCompo : IComponennt 
{
    public Draw(Color tint) {

        //apply here transformations available in list of GetTransformation()

        .... 
        // draw
    }
}
```

Just an idea.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. I thought of this but the problem is only a very small fraction of all my IComponents will have effects applied to them. So having them all have to go through and check a list might be inefficient and would require a lot of repeated code (go thru list in draw method) for each of the 70 different IComponent derived classes I currently have. I could have them all derive from a concrete BaseComponent class that does this loop thru check, but then it will be a waste of this 1 inheritance slot am allowed in c# since a small fraction of them will use effects.

Comment: @user964123: you can add a `null` check, yo can do another method to interface, like `Draw(Color tint, IEnumerable<ITransformation>)`, which will execute drawing with transformation.